# Template functions to check "is int"/"is double"/etc

Tags: c++, templates

I am a bit shaky with C++ template syntax, so I'm not sure if what I'm envisioning is possible, and if it is, I'm unclear on correct syntax.

I would like to implement template functions like `template<int> bool is( std::string& )`, `template<double> bool is( std::string& )`, etc. so that I can call `is <int> (...)` or `is <double> (...)` instead of `isInt(...)` or `isDouble(...)`, etc. Is this possible? If so, how would you code the function signatures?

With my tenuous grasp of template syntax, my attempt was:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template<int>
bool is( std::string& raw )
{
    if ( raw.empty() ) return false;
    char* p;
    int num = strtol( raw.c_str(), &p, 10);
    return ( ( *p != '\0' ) ? false : true );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::string str("42");
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is <int> ( str ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This failed with the following errors:

```
>g++ -g main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:16:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘is(std::string&)’
     std::cout << std::boolalpha << is <int> ( str ) << std::endl;
                                                   ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: template<int <anonymous> > bool is(std::string&)
 bool is( std::string& raw )
      ^
main.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Comment: Non-type template arguments expects *values* not types. I recommend you read about [*template specialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: You'll probably get answers soon, but my suggestion is simply "don't". It obfuscates the code with template related syntax, only so you could have a little bit of syntactic sugar at the call site.

Comment: @StoneThrow sorry that first comment was just a misunderstanding, deleted it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My comment to your post withstanding, the way to do this easily is with a simple template that uses the `std::istringstream` class to parse:

```
template<typename T>
bool is(std::string const& raw) {
  std::istringstream parser(raw);

  T t; parser >> t;
  return !parser.fail() && parser.eof();
}
```

The obvious caveat is that `T` must be default constructable. But on the plus side, the above will work for user defined types as well, so long as they implement `operator >>`.

Comment: That's pretty clever and exposes something else I am unfamiliar with due to lack of use: the `>>` operator. So if I interpret this correctly, `istringstream::>>` operator will "attempt to" parse the string into its right hand operand - is that right?

Comment: @StoneThrow - `operator>>` is in fact a special function name. C++ code can implement it for user defined types and it will be chosen in overload restitution when `A >> B` is written with those types. The standard stream classes (being user defined) already overload them to allow "input" of all fundamental types. But if you write your class, you can add a `operator>>(istream&, myClass&)` function yourself. And yes, if the required parsing fails, the parser state will return `fail() == true`.

Comment: Problem with that solution: `is<int>("1976 Dodge Van")` is `true`. You might want to change that to `!parser.fail() && parser.eof()` - I'm not quite sure though that there isn't another stream states "detail" lurking.

Comment: @peterchen - There probably is. I never could remember the various meanings of the state bit combinations. This is a fairly naive solution, I admit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use template specialisation for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template<class T> bool is(std::string& raw) = delete;

template<>
bool is<int>( std::string& raw )
{
    if ( raw.empty() ) return false;
    char* p;
    int num = strtol( raw.c_str(), &p, 10);
    return ( ( *p != '\0' ) ? false : true );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::string str("42");
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is <int> ( str ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can read more about in [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Comment: If I may make a suggestion. You can add `= delete` to the primary template. That will give a decent error early during compile time (as opposed to link time) that the type isn't supported.

Comment: One thing I learned from this is that the "function prototype" or "unspecialized template prototype" is required. (what is the correct term for line 4 of your code?). As opposed to an equivalent non-template function where the prototype would not be needed if is parsed before its use.

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't know that this was possible - good to know. Thank you for the hint.